# build gcc for static linking

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake

I built my own gcc from source using

```
/configure --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --program-suffix=-6.4 --prefix=/home/martin/devel/gcc-6.4.0-build
make
```

Everything went well except when I want to build my shared library with static runtime using cmake like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /home/martin/devel/gcc-6.4.0-build/bin/gcc-6.4)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /home/martin/devel/gcc-6.4.0-build/bin/g++-6.4)
project(Foo)
add_library(FooLib SHARED main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(FooLib -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static)
```

When I try to make this I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/martin/devel/gcc-6.4.0-build/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.4.0/crtbeginT.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `__TMC_END__' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/home/martin/devel/gcc-6.4.0-build/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.4.0/crtbeginT.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
```

So I suspected that the gcc wasn't been built properly, don't know how to do that.

Comment: I'd suggest you first pick a single programming language, either C or C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `--with-pic` in your GCC configure line. Though apparently there are some bugs sometimes: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58638 so you should add `CFLAGS="-fPIC" CXXFLAGS="-fPIC"` for safety.

Comment: I'll try. The only thing I don't get is where is this from. The --with-pic is never mentioned when I type ./configure --help

Comment: it's from libstdc++'s `configure`. GCC's build system is basically a good dozen distinct software / libraries : the top level `configure` passes all the options it gets to all the "child" `configure` : libstdc++, binutils, GMP, MPFR, etc. But all the options of the child scripts aren't repertoried in the top-level one (sadly).

Comment: Well... the good news is that it compiled. The bad news is that ldd is showing a bunch of .sos ... in case I am reading it correctly. I assume that list should be empty when I link a shared library with the -static... but I guess this question is solved

Comment: > "I assume that list should be empty when I link a shared library with the -static..." : I don't think this is possible: at the bare minimum, shared libraries must link to linux-vdso and ld-linux-$PLATFORM IIRC.

Comment: but when I deleted the entire  -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static from the cmake line and the ldd was the same as with it... I am trying to add also the --disable-shared as mentioned in the link... I'll let know how it finished.   Btw the ldd list was  linux-vdso.so.1,libstdc++.so.6 ,libm.so.6,libgcc_s.so.1 ,libc.so.6 ,/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2